# missing semicolon (;) at end of sql statement error

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I tried to execute this statement

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES (2, 1, 10), (2, 2, 4), (2, 12, 0)
```

And I got this error:

> missing semicolon (;) at end of sql statement

What's wrong with my SQL statement?

Comment: What database are you using? Are you sure the error comes from the database?

Comment: You've left relevant information out of the question. There are multiple different correct answers, for different database engines. Which database system are you using?

Comment: @hvd LOLWHAT? It's literally saying "missing ; at the end of the statement" you don't need to know for that! Of course like you I am immensely curious, "What pedantic SQL server is this?"

Comment: @AlecTeal Some database systems don't support inserting multiple rows with `VALUES`, and give nonsensical errors for what they see as a nonsensical syntax.

Comment: @hvd I asked you answered, fair enough.

Comment: @Kobi as I mention in my answer, I've never worked with a DB that was so pedantic it'd demand semi-colons at the end of statements, but the diagnostic is clear!

Comment: MySQL anyone? `;` all the way...

Comment: @fancyPants [MySQL only needs the semicolons when combining multiple statements.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05fac/1)

Comment: @hvd So I see you never worked with the command line tool that comes with MySQL. sqlfiddle is just a frontend that sets the `;` for you.

Comment: @fancyPants The command-line tool uses `;` to determine at which point to send the entered command to the server. If you use some other method of accessing MySQL without going through that command-line client (when programming, the access will usually not be through the command-line client), the semicolon is mostly optional.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a ; at the end of your statement.

It's literally telling you "PUT `;` AT THE END OF YOUR STATEMENT"

Also what SQL server is this? I know MariaDB/MySQL & SQLite are not that pedantic.

Comment: That's one possibility. The other is that the parser is getting confused because the database doesn't support the syntax to insert multiple rows with `VALUES`. Until the OP clarifies which database is used, there's no way of knowing whether this answer is correct.

Comment: @hvd if we can't trust the diagnostics.... I have faith in the parser. But yeah I'm also curious, I've never used anything that pedantic!

Comment: I don't deserve 40 rep for this

Comment: 50! Have another upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(Field1, Field2, Field3)
VALUES (2, 1, 10), (2, 2, 4), (2, 12, 0);
```

Semicolon is the standard way to separate each SQL statement in database systems that allow more than one SQL statement to be executed in the same call to the server.

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer, not just a code

Comment: The semicolon character is a statement terminator.